# Preseed proxy setting for local repository

Tags: repository, preseed, localrepository, apt-cacher-ng

I'm trying to set up a preseed configuration for Ubuntu 14.04 network installation from the example on the official documentation. I am affected by [the proxy bug on choose-mirror](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=642159). I'm using an `apt-cacher-ng` proxy. Due to this, adding a local repository fails, as the key cannot be downloaded through the `apt-cacher-ng` proxy. Usually I get an error about the key itself. Then I tried using a random gpg key from the mirror specified in `apt-cacher-ng` backend (`in.archive.ubuntu.com`, in this case). The error about the key vanished (at least the related prompt didn't appear), but the local repository was still not added, even though I had set:

```
d-i debian-installer/allow_unauthenticated boolean true
```

Using my campus mirror directly, thus avoiding the proxy, throws up an error about `grub-pc` failing to install (perhaps due to some problem with the mirror?).
What can I do use both the cacher and the local repository together? I can think of the following possibilites:

1. `apt-cacher-ng` has an option to let some domains/urls slide, instead of outright rejecting them.
2. `debian-installer` has a way to use the local repo without a key.
3. `debian-installer` has a question for more specific proxy settings (e.g., only for `apt` (ideal), `no_proxy` lists, etc.).
4. Install one package by itself (which contains the key for the repository and a `sources.list.d` entry), before `d-i` starts installing packages.
5. `wget` the key and the list entry directly and add it, do `apt-get update` and other package installation via script in post install.
6. Find some way to fix the `grub-pc` error when using the local campus mirror directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such, I am using a workaround. The proxy I have set in preseeding is an HTTP proxy, so naturally HTTPS and FTP connections are unaffected. However, the installer **does not** support HTTPS as a transport mechanism (possibly `apt-transport-https` has to be installed somehow). So the option that remains is setting up an FTP server for the signing key, which I did using `vsftpd`. I didn't want the `apt-cacher` to do any work for the local repository, so I set up `vsftpd` to serve as an FTP repository as well.